# Swift Alamofire how to handle all requests from loop

Tags: swift, alamofire

I need to execute loop with 10 Alamofire requests. How to hanble, when all 10 requsts will be finished?

Comment: Your question is too vague and unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a wrapper class to send network request. eg

```
class HttpRequest {
    static var requestCount:Int = 0

    class func sendRequest(onCompletion:(Bool)->()) {
        // Send alamofire request here 
        // below code is just a sample 
        Alamofire.request(...).validate().response(..completionHandler..) {

        // Check response & increment request count
        requestCount += 1

       if requestCount == 10 {
           // calling completion handler here
           onCompletion(true)
        }
     }
   }   
}
```

Now use it as

```
HttpRequest.sendRequest(onCompletion:(isCompleted){

// Whatever you wanted to do after 10 request gets completed

})
```

PS: Above provided code is just a prototype. Actual syntax may differ

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the requests in promises (third party) or Operations (first party) would let you do some dependency management for the requests and code to execute when they're all complete.

For a quick and dirty fix you could use dispatch groups.

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
var responses = [DataResponse<String>]()

dispatchGroup.enter()
Alamofire.request("https://www.google.com").responseString { response in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        responses.append(response)
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
}

dispatchGroup.enter()
Alamofire.request("https://www.yahoo.com").responseString { response in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        responses.append(response)
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
}

dispatchGroup.enter()
Alamofire.request("https://www.bing.com").responseString { response in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        responses.append(response)
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
}

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) { 
    print("Got \(responses.count) responses")
}
```

Comment: How to to achieve the same when the number of requests to make is not known in advance. Like for example in my case I need to download a set of images from different URLs one after the other. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

use DispatchGroups best way to achieve this

```
var myGroup = DispatchGroup()

 firstAlamofireRequest(){
  myGroup.enter()
}

 SecondAlamofireRequest(){
  myGroup.enter()
}

onFirstAlmoFireResponse(){
 myGroup.leave()
}

onSecondAlmoFireResponse(){
 myGroup.leave()
}
```

and when the groupDespatcher Finishes all

this method will be called

```
 myGroup.notify(qos: DispatchQoS.background, flags: DispatchWorkItemFlags.assignCurrentContext, queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
           // what to do after all requests are done 

        }
```